# Use SmsManager to open the default sms app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sms

I am building a **Xamarin Android** application *(API version>=23)* that should call the SMS default application with a prefilled-in number and prefilled-in  text.

I figure out how to send the SMS using `SmsManager`

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage("Number", null, "Text", null, null);
```

The above line send the SMS text directly after the user grants the permission to the app. Is there a way to open the default SMS app instead with prefilled in destination number and text, and let the user press send ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting up an Intent can bring up the default SMS massager app:

```
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendto);
intent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("smsto:" + "555-555-1212"));
intent.PutExtra("sms_body", "StackOverflow rocks");
StartActivity(intent);
```

It is doubtful that there is no SMS registered app, but you can use the Intent that you populated to check for for which app/activity will launched:

```
var packagename = intent.ResolveActivity(PackageManager)?.PackageName;
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)), does my app in this case also need the SEND_SMS capability ?

Comment: No i don't, just figure that out :^p